# Filtering if only one filter is selected

Tags: php, mysql

I have to make a car website that filters cars depending on a preset mysql database.
I have got it to filter if all are selected (eg: Honda, white, petrol and not on special - it will show that car) but if I just wanted to see all the Honda's (for example) nothing shows.

This is the code I have:

```
if(isset($_GET['make']) || isset($_GET['colour']) || isset($_GET['fueltype']) ||          isset($_GET['special'])){

if(isset($_GET['make'])){
$make = $_GET['make'];
}

if(isset($_GET['colour'])){
$colour = $_GET['colour'];
}

if(isset($_GET['fueltype'])){
$fueltype = $_GET['fueltype'];
}

if(isset($_GET['special'])){
$special = $_GET['special'];
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE MAKE ='$make' AND COLOUR = '$colour' AND FUELTYPE = '$fueltype' AND SPECIAL = '$special'");
}



else{
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Cars");
}
```

the else statement makes all the cars show up when you open the page before filtering.

Comment: **NOTE:** There is a high possibility of [SQL-Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Answer (score 0):

escape can mean: mysql_escape_string, check against a list of valid/allowed values, or whatever you want after good thinking.

```
$where = "";
$separator = " WHERE ";

if(isset($_GET['make'])){
    $make = $_GET['make'];
    !! escape here
    $where .= $separator . " MAKE = '$make' ";
    $separator = " AND ";
}

if(isset($_GET['colour'])){
    $colour = $_GET['colour'];
    !! escape here
    $where .= $separator . " COLOUR = '$colour' ";
    $separator = " AND ";
}

... 

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Cars " . $where);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it. Please do something for sql injection attacks. This is only example.

```
$query  =   "SELECT * FROM Cars ";
$where  =   array();

if(isset($_GET['make'])){
    $where['make'] = $_GET['make'];
}

if(isset($_GET['colour'])){
    $where['colour'] = $_GET['colour'];
}

if(isset($_GET['fueltype'])){
    $where['fueltype'] = $_GET['fueltype'];
}

if(isset($_GET['special'])){
    $where['special'] = $_GET['special'];
}

$string =   '';
if(count($where)>0){
    $i=0;
    foreach($where as $key => $value)
    {
        if($i==0){
            $string .=  " WHERE $key = $value ";
        }else{
            $string .=  " AND $key = $value ";
        }
    $i++;   
    }
}
$query  .=  $string;

mysqli_query($query);
```

Comment: Add http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php and this is the best solution.

Comment: what is a sql injection attacks? its only a college project it wont be live on the internet must i still do something about it, and if so how?

Comment: @user2136106 see [this](http://www.zdnet.com/sql-injection-attack-what-is-it-and-how-to-prevent-it-7000000881/) and [this](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/). Although this may be collage project but you should learn to prevent sql injection. Also in collage project applying security will be plus point for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['make']) || isset($_GET['colour']) || isset($_GET['fueltype']) ||          isset($_GET['special'])){
$where="WHERE ";
if(isset($_GET['make'])){
$make = $_GET['make'];
$where .="MAKE ='$make' AND";
}

if(isset($_GET['colour'])){
$colour = $_GET['colour'];
$where .="COLOUR = '$colour' AND";
}

if(isset($_GET['fueltype'])){
$fueltype = $_GET['fueltype'];
$where .="FUELTYPE = '$fueltype' AND";
}

if(isset($_GET['special'])){
$special = $_GET['special'];
$where .="SPECIAL = '$special";
}
$where=rtrim($where,'AND');

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Cars".$where);
}



else{
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Cars");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the security issues you could replace your whole code with something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE 1 = 1";

if (isset($_GET['make']))
    $query .= ' AND MAKE = ' . (int) $_GET['make'];

if (isset($_GET['colour']))
    $query .= ' AND COLOUR = ' . (int) $_GET['colour'];

if (isset($_GET['fueltype']))
    $query .= ' AND FUELTYPE = ' . (int) $_GET['fueltype'];

if (isset($_GET['special']))
    $query .= ' AND SPECIAL = ' . (int) $_GET['special'];

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

Comment: why do your if statements not have {} ? how do i add the else in here with out them? sorry if this is a stupid question this is all new to me

Comment: if the `if` statements don't have brackets, the next instruction will be executed only if the condition is true. You can add else right after the instruction, and the rules about brackets are the same as above. It's a bad practice anyway, and you should always use brackets